# Contour plot that excludes regions outside of a constraint

Tags: plotting, legending, regions

In the attached figure, I calculate the minimum value of the dependent variable represented by the bar legend. This minimum value is based on `NonlinearModelFit` and some provided constraints:

```
-30 <= w - x <= 30, 100 <= w + x <= 140, -30 <= y - z <= 30, 30 <= y + z <= 70
```

In the contour plot, `plot1`, I only want to provide the region and contours that lie within the constraints.

```
data1 = {{56.37, 50.87, 30.02, 17.03, 374.4351},
   {58.65, 55.42, 35.92, 9.40, 378.5311},
   {50.10, 57.93, 28.12, 24.72, 382.9404},
   {55.00, 64.06, 35.25, 9.81, 385.3239},
   {78.81, 52.21, 16.75, 37.73, 360.5262},
   {76.00, 47.50, 14.29, 42.63, 366.8247},
   {64.81, 75.03, 29.78, 32.47, 385.2263},
   {43.06, 62.17, 37.58, 18.74, 392.6430},
   {59.77, 75.55, 17.08, 13.27, 395.0901},
   {50.00, 67.25, 17.56, 23.23, 388.2105},
   {57.76, 46.75, 6.26, 28.67, 370.8931},
   {60.76, 39.63, 29.47, 9.35, 369.7973},
   {74.65, 58.10, 33.52, 20.29, 367.5070},
   {55.96, 82.95, 21.26, 12.08, 400.6387},
   {67.07, 60.93, 17.52, 28.54, 370.7206},
   {64.85, 45.87, 18.76, 29.23, 365.4720},
   {73.63, 51.02, 47.56, 18.52, 374.0817},
   {63.01, 62.00, 37.39, 20.57, 377.1032},
   {55.59, 54.25, 17.57, 37.30, 381.5565},
   {40.09, 61.71, 23.15, 17.05, 392.1980},
   {55.71, 70.71, 26.42, 34.66, 387.3536},
   {72.82, 63.59, 38.31, 26.96, 373.2345},
   {65.38, 67.52, 17.27, 18.42, 383.0928},
   {49.29, 54.70, 39.88, 19.15, 388.0926},
   {71.71, 54.68, 17.19, 46.81, 376.3287},
   {55.72, 81.59, 22.85, 27.56, 395.6144},
   {54.17, 66.65, 29.88, 13.49, 386.2271},
   {77.86, 52.02, 23.08, 46.20, 373.2058},
   {49.71, 73.08, 15.15, 28.71, 392.3962},
   {65.28, 36.20, 30.76, 7.92, 365.2050},
   {61.06, 51.33, 41.41, 16.76, 378.2849},
   {57.75, 58.82, 37.50, 29.80, 384.0721},
   {54.26, 60.38, 39.28, 28.57, 386.0149},
   {57.26, 77.45, 39.28, 28.57, 392.2751},
   {54.11, 65.20, 29.93, 2.12, 391.5410},
   {60.35, 46.28, 21.31, 16.24, 366.9868},
   {50.07, 53.09, 17.56, 42.15, 387.0709},
   {75.99, 51.62, 12.91, 19.89, 367.7338},
   {47.93, 61.38, 24.13, 25.33, 385.1901},
   {77.36, 56.96, 8.75, 25.48, 366.6283},
   {44.14, 73.64, 12.28, 29.72, 395.9586},
   {62.19, 49.12, 45.77, 23.11, 383.3738},
   {45.99, 74.64, 14.97, 33.55, 396.5276},
   {68.35, 61.05, 18.25, 44.76, 377.2609},
   {72.87, 48.91, 19.44, 31.70, 359.7447},
   {56.38, 81.44, 21.77, 20.34, 396.5157},
   {58.51, 54.46, 25.93, 10.56, 375.8848},
   {60.40, 45.45, 2.37, 28.53, 372.2086},
   {55.99, 59.94, 26.31, 35.04, 382.6633},
   {55.40, 75.96, 26.44, 25.93, 391.2757}};

data3 = {{56.37, 50.87},
   {58.65, 55.42},
   {50.10, 57.93},
   {55.00, 64.06},
   {78.81, 52.21},
   {76.00, 47.50},
   {64.81, 75.03},
   {43.06, 62.17},
   {59.77, 75.55},
   {50.00, 67.25},
   {57.76, 46.75},
   {60.76, 39.63},
   {74.65, 58.10},
   {55.96, 82.95},
   {67.07, 60.93},
   {64.85, 45.87},
   {73.63, 51.02},
   {63.01, 62.00},
   {55.59, 54.25},
   {40.09, 61.71},
   {55.71, 70.71},
   {72.82, 63.59},
   {65.38, 67.52},
   {49.29, 54.70},
   {71.71, 54.68},
   {55.72, 81.59},
   {54.17, 66.65},
   {77.86, 52.02},
   {49.71, 73.08},
   {65.28, 36.20},
   {61.06, 51.33},
   {57.75, 58.82},
   {54.26, 60.38},
   {57.26, 77.45},
   {54.11, 65.20},
   {60.35, 46.28},
   {50.07, 53.09},
   {75.99, 51.62},
   {47.93, 61.38},
   {77.36, 56.96},
   {44.14, 73.64},
   {62.19, 49.12},
   {45.99, 74.64},
   {68.35, 61.05},
   {72.87, 48.91},
   {56.38, 81.44},
   {58.51, 54.46},
   {60.40, 45.45},
   {55.99, 59.94},
   {55.40, 75.96}};

model[w_, x_, y_, z_] := 
  aa*w^2 + bb*x^2 + cc*y ^2 + dd*z^2 + ee*w*x + ff*w*y + gg*w*z + 
   hh*x*y + ii*x*z + jj*y*z + kk*w + ll*x + mm*y + nn*z + oo;

fit = NonlinearModelFit[data1, 
   model[w, x, y, z], {aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, jj, kk, ll,
     mm, nn, oo}, {w, x, y, z}];

f[w_, x_, y_, z_] := Normal[fit[w, x, y, z]]

f1[w_, x_] := Normal[fit[w, x, 15, 35]]

plot1 = ContourPlot[f1[w, x], {w, 35, 85}, {x, 35, 85}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85}, 
     None}, {{35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85}, None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12], 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], 
  PlotLabel -> Style["(a)", Black, Medium, Bold], 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[data3]}, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
  ImageSize -> 200, Contours -> 30, PlotLegends -> Automatic];

FindMinimum[{f[w, x, y, z], -30 <= w - x <= 30, 
  100 <= w + x <= 140, -30 <= y - z <= 30, 
  30 <= y + z <= 70}, {{w, 75}, {x, 50}, {y, 15}, {z, 15}}];
```

[image: Mathematica notebook]

Comment: Just posting a data dump and an image of your notebook is a good way to get people interesting in your question. Please post your actual Mathematica code, not an image of it. Without real code no one will be able to work with it to see what you might have done wrong, nor will they be able to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: Have a look at `RegionFunction` in the options to `ContourPlot`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `RegionFunction` will do what you want.

```
plot1 =
 ContourPlot[f1[w, x], {w, 35, 85}, {x, 35, 85},
   RegionFunction -> Function[{w, x}, -30 <= w - x <= 30 && 100 <= w + x <= 140],
   FrameTicks ->
     {{{35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85}, None}, {{35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85}, None}},
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12],
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"],
   PlotLabel -> Style["(a)", Black, Medium, Bold],
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[data3]},
   FrameStyle -> Thick,
   ImageSize -> 200,
   Contours -> 30,
   PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]